# С. вычисление градиента функции многих переменных

Tags: c, массивы, математика, оптимизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попыталась следовать следующему алгоритму

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

изначальный вариант выглядел так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return (x * x );
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double del = 0.1;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fx;
    fx = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fy;
    fy = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* grad;
    grad = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];
        fx[i] = f(x[i]);
    }
    double a = 1 / del;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = y[i] + del;
        fy[i] = f(y[i]);
        grad[i] = a * (fy[i] - fx[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf ", grad[i]);
    }

}
```

Затем я поняла, что должна передавать массив в качестве аргумента в функцию. Но так и не поняла, как сделать это правильно.(выводится мусор) И необходимость в массивах fx и fy...которой, вероятно, нет. Пожалуйста , помогите откорректировать , т.к. понимаю, что наверняка есть косяк в моей реализации алгоритма. К сожалению, я даже не понимаю какие входные данные я должна подавать и какой результат должна выдавать корректно работающая программа. Я очень буду благодарна за помощь, очень хочу разобраться в этом, но пока на этом моменте застопорилась....

```
double f(double arr[], int size)
{
    int a = sizeof(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i];
    }
    return *arr;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double del = 0.1;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fx;
    fx = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* fy;
    fy = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* grad;
    grad = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];
        fx[i] = f(x,n);
    }
    double a = 1 / del;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = y[i] + del;
        fy[i] = f(y,n);
        grad[i] = a * (fy[i] - fx[i]);
        y[i] = x[i];

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf ", grad[i]);
    }

}
```

Вариант Mikhailo (изменен):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>


void grad(double* y,    // Возвращаемый массив
    double* x,    // Точка, в которой вычисляется градиент
    int n,        // Число переменных
    double d,     // Та самая дельта
    double (*f)(double*, int)) { // Исследуемая функция
    double f0 = f(x, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double save = x[i];
        x[i] += d;
        double f1 = f(x, n);
        x[i] = save;
        y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
    }
}

double f(double* x, int n) {
    int i; double sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += x[i] * x[i]* x[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int n; int i;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
    }
    grad(y, x, n, 0.001, f);
    printf("grad f(x0,x1,..xn)\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %lf ",y[i]);
    }
   // printf("grad f(1,2) = %lf i + %lf j\n", y[0], y[1]);
}
```

Comment: "функции многих переменных" - где?

Comment: @Igor простите, но я вас не очень поняла..

Comment: Где в Вашем коде функция многих переменных - `f(х1, х2, ..., xn)`?

Comment: @Igor А как..как я её могу задать?Я думала, что в функцию передаю массивы значений.

Comment: Можно передавать и массивом. Это просто один из способов передачи вектора значений в функцию.

Comment: @Mikhailo так что я делаю не так ? :(

Comment: @Lus_Babaika Значение функции должно вычисляться с использованием всех элементов массива. Здесь `double f(double arr[], int size) {...}` Вы возводите все элементы массива в квадрат и возвращаете первый из этих квадратов.

Comment: Я не знаю, потому что не понимаю, что вам нужно. Библиотечная функция поиска градиента для произвольной функции F? Или найти градиент для какой-то конкретной функцтии? для какой?

Comment: @Igor так как вернуть не только первый?

Comment: @Mikhailo для произвольной функции и для любого числа n.

Comment: @Lus_Babaika Какая у Вас функция нескольких переменных? Какая у нее формула должна быть внутри функции `double f(double arr[], int size) {...}`?

Comment: Тогда вы должны не описывать свою функцию `f`, а передавать ее в функцию вычисления градиента.

Comment: @Mikhailo было бы здорово, если бы я вас поняла, но , к сожалению, нет :(

Answer (score 1):

Вот, смотрите. `grad` вычисляет градиент - это вектор, который возвращается в массив `y`. Массив `x` - точка, в которой считаем градиент. `n` - размерность вектора. `f` - функция от `n` переменных, градиент которой ищем.

```
include <stdio.h>

void grad(double* y,    // Возвращаемый массив
          double* x,    // Точка, в которой вычисляется градиент
          int n,        // Число переменных
          double d,     // Та самая дельта
          double (*f)(double*, int)) { // Исследуемая функция
    double f0 = f(x, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double save = x[i];
        x[i] += d;
        double f1 = f(x, n);
        x[i] = save;
        y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
        }
    }

double f(double* x, int n) {
    return x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1];
    }

int main() {
    double x[] = {1, 2};
    double y[2];
    grad(y, x, 2, 0.001, f);
    printf("grad f(1,2) = %lf i + %lf j\n", y[0], y[1]);
    }
```

Далее идет пример - функция от двух переменных `f(u,v)`, которая равна `u^2 + v^2`. Эти две переменные передаются как массив. И для нее вычисляем градиент в точке `(1,2)`.

По-моему, все должно быть понятно.

Если бы стояла задача для функции от конкретного количества переменных, можно было бы использовать не массивы, а явное `f(u,v)` например. Но у вас НЕТ функции, для которой мы считаем градиент, а потому пришлось писать обобщенную функцию, чпособную работать с любой функцией от `n` переменных. Лишь бы массивы были нужного размера.

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое! Теперь яснее. Вы уж извините  , немного изменила ваш вариант для произвольного кол-ва переменных. Надеюсь, более менее корректно. Вот только возникли пару вопросов. Попробовала для начала запустить программу для `u^2 + v^2..+j^2` там у всех после запятой ,00100..но уже когда попробовала использовать функцию в кубе, там уже ситуация поинтереснее. отсюда возник вопрос. Как посчитать с заданной точностью? Я понимаю, что в `grad` функцию  параметром придется вводить E и вводить while.Но..что с чем сравнивать, чтобы достичь точности?

Comment: И еще один момент. По поводу самой функции `f`. Не обязательно же ведь, что всегда функция будет иметь какой-то такой вид `u^2 + v^2..+j^2` , в том плане, что все составляющие идентичны. Т.е. во всех других случаях придется прописывать всё ручками, верно? (как это сделали вы в своем примере)

Comment: Ручками прописывать надо только саму функцию, которую передаем в `grad`. Было бы странно вычислять градиент функции, кода которой нет, правда? Что до точности - то численное дифференцирование - очень неприятная с точки зрения математики задача. Для повышения точности нужно брать малые дельты, но при этом начнет теряться точность из-за машинного представления. Можно использовать формулы втторого, третьего и высших порядков - но это уже совсем другой вопрос и в комментарии на него не ответить. Возьмите какой-нибудь учебник по численным методам, типа Самарского.

Comment: Или вот, например - https://dwg.ru/dnl/5302